Finding rotation matrix that transforms set of $x_i$'s into $y_i$'s
Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are $d\times n$ matrices in $\mathbb{R}$ with orthonormal columns, $n<d$. How do I find $d\times d$ orthogonal matrix $U$ with $\operatorname{det}(U)=1$, such that $Y=U X$ for all $i$?
I've considered taking the unitary factor of polar decomposition of $Y X^\dagger$, but that often gives me result with negative determinant.
Related implementation question

It might be useful to see an example of what you're looking to solve in your question. As it is, you currently won't have a unique solution (trivially, consider $n=1$ and any $d>2$). Is that important? Or are you looking to characterise the set of valid rotation matrices?

This problem, in the case that $d = 3$, is known as Wahba's problem. Without the $\det = 1$ requirement, this would be the orthogonal procrustes problem.
To make a long story short, here's a solution that I believe gives an optimal answer, though I don't have a proof or citation off the top of my head. Let $YX^\dagger = U\Sigma V^T$ be a singular value decomposition. If $UV^T$ (the unitary factor of the polar decomposition) has determinant $1$, then that's the best matrix $U$. If $UV^T$ has determinant $-1$, it turns out that the best choice for an orthogonal matrix with determinant $1$ is given by $UDV^T$, where $D$ is the diagonal matrix
$$
D = \text{diag}(1,\dots,1,-1).
$$

Hm, least squares solution finds matrix with small Frobenius norm, polar decomposition finds the closest matrix to that, is that supposed to be same as maximizing the trace of the solution? Here's the concrete example where this approach gives a matrix with much smaller trace than possible in $d=4$ where I can do exact optimization

BTW, I think this is different from Wabha problem. I'm looking for orthogonal $U$ with the smallest total angle which reduces to maximizing trace of $U$

It looks like there's an SDP relaxation of the problem in Song's "LINEAR PROGRAMMING ON THE STIEFEL MANIFOLD" paper, but it's only exact when rank of the rotation matrix to restricted to be$<d-n$
